# I want to print multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to print this array please somebody help...

```
$ar[1] = array(
 1 => array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
 ),
 2 => array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
 ),
);
```

how to print a, b, c...?

```
$ar[1][0]->a;
```

or

```
$at[1][0]['a'];
```

not getting desired value...

Comment: use this `echo $at[1][1]['a'];`

Comment: @MujeebuRahman is correct, remember that you are specifying the index so `0` won't work because you gave index `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There Is Multiple Ways To Do This..

**1.**

```
<?php
    echo $at[1][1]['a'];
    echo $at[1][1]['b'];
    echo $at[1][1]['c'];
    echo $at[1][2]['a'];
    echo $at[1][2]['b'];
    echo $at[1][2]['c'];
?>
```

> `$ar[1]`   It's array ,  `$at[1][1]` secondOne `[1]` is index

**2.**

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($ar[1]); echo '<pre/>';
```

**3.**

```
var_dump($ar[1]);
```

**4.**

```
using For
```

**5.**

```
using foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ar, 0); i++) {
   for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($ar, 1); j++) {
   echo $ar[i][j];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo $at[1][1]['a'];
echo $at[1][2]['a'];
?>
```

If you are not using loop, this way you can echo

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($myArray,true).'</pre>';
```

in your example the array you show doesn't have member $ar[1][0]['a']
it has member $ar[1][**1**]['a']